# Assign a value to a controller property in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8

I am trying to pass an int variable between views in Swift but I'm not sure how to access the other View controller's property.

In Objective C I would do something like this

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
AnsViewController *ansViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ansView"];
ansViewController.num = theNum;
[self presentViewController:ansViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And in the other viewcontroller.h file I would write this to declare the property to get the data

```
@property (nonatomic) int num;
```

Now for Swift I have this

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let ansViewController : UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ansView") as UIViewController
ansViewController.num = theNum;
self.presentViewController(ansViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

and in the other .swift file for the other view controller I declared num by doing

```
let num: int
```

I'm pretty sure that isn't the right way to do it because I get an error on this line

```
ansViewController.num = theNum;
```

and it says, "UIViewController does not have a member named num"  How would I resolve this error and what have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this `let num: int` line? Can you add more code?

Comment: I put the let num : int line in the swift file for the AnsViewController right under all the @IBOutlet var lines

Answer (score 5):

**The Problem**

In Objective C, you've explicitly defined ansViewController as an AnsViewController*, which has the property num.

In your Swift code, though, you've explicitly defined ansViewController as a UIViewController, not an AnsViewController. So, the compiler has no idea if this is actually an AnsViewController, or some other UIViewController subclass, or just a vanilla UIViewController.

**Now for the solution.**

We're going to try to downcast the returned value as an AnsViewController, then access that property if the downcast succeeds (I'm assuming it always will, but out-of-context from the rest of your code and nibs, I can't be sure).

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

// To be safe, let's attempt to downcast the returned value as an AnsViewController
if let ansViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ansView") as? AnsViewController {
    // We get here if the "as?" succeeds with a non-nil value
    ansViewController.num = theNum;
    self.presentViewController(ansViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
} else {
    // Out of context, I can't see why this case would (or could) ever happen
}
```

Now, if you know this will always succeed (from what I can see, the return value of -instantiateWith... is deterministic), then you can be a bit more concise:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

// Force the downcast as an AnsViewController (this could crash at runtime
// if the return value is nil or not an AnsViewController, so again,
// the previous example is safer
let ansViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ansView") as AnsViewController
ansViewController.num = theNum;
self.presentViewController(ansViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to clear all errors but creates one new one. The line where ansViewController.num = theNum is gives me an error saying CInt is not convertible to Int.  I also had to change the part where i declare num to var num : Int = 0 to get rid of errors. Should I have done that?

Comment: I think that I am getting that error because I had to use bridgeToObjectiveC().intValue to get the int value from a text field

Comment: I'm not sure where theNum is coming from, but try this: `ansViewController.num = Int(theNum)`.

Comment: And the reason that works is because Swift is very strict in typing, and does not treat Ints and CInts as interchangeable. You need to init a new Int object from the CInt object. Int(cInt: CInt) is essentially what is being called, an init method that creates an Int from a CInt.